# Checking browser in ExtJS5

Tags: extjs5

I was looking for `Ext.isIE` in the Ext JS 5 API, but I couldn't find any option in Ext class documentation.

Is there any alternate configuration in Ext JS 5?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (Ext.browser.is.IE) {
    // IE specific code here
}

if (Ext.browser.is.WebKit) {
    // WebKit specific code here
}

console.log("Version " + Ext.browser.version);
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.browser

Answer (score 0):

You can still check the browser using Ext.isIE and all other similar methods.

The difference in Ext JS5 is that the browser sniffing code has been moved to a sencha-core package. If you're looking for sniffing code it's there in Ext.env.Browser.js